# How do you make this menu slide using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I was able to get this far with creating my sliding menu, however, I'm not sure what I've entered wrong because the menu won't slide for me. I'm trying to get the menu to slide to the right when the 'tab' is clicked, then when the 'tab' is click again, I want the menu to retract to the left side of the screen.

In short, my question is:

## 1. Why won't the menu slide?

```
<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tab").toggle(function() { 
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 500px);
        $("#tab").html('-');
    }, function() {
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '-600' }, 500px);
        $("#tab").html('+');
    }); });​ </script>

<style type="text/css">


#menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:520px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:helvetica;
    color:#FFFFFF
    opacity:.9;  }

      a{ 
        padding-right:60px; 
        text-decoration:none;
        margin:40px;
        color:#FFFFFF
        } h1{
     font-size:20px;
     padding:40px;
     color:#FFFFFF
     text-margin:50px;
    } h2{
     font-size:60px;
     padding:70px;
     color:#FFFFFF } h3{
     font-size:15px;
     padding:50px;
     color:#FFFFFF }

 #tab{
      position:absolute;
      height:90px;
      width:90px;
      right:-6%;
      top:0px;
      background-color:#000000;
      font-family:helvetica;
      color:#FFFFFF;
      font-size:50px;
      cursor:pointer; }


</style>

</head>



<body>

<div id="menu"><h1>

                   <a class="navItem" href="url">about me</a>
              
                    <a class="navItem" href="url">book</a> 
                
            <a class="navItem" href="url">resume</a> 
                
                    <a class="navItem" href="url">ask</a> 
                
                    <a class="navItem" href="url">archive</a></h1>


<h2>title</h2>


<h3>websitetitle</h3>

            

<div id="tab"> +

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: "What values do I have to adjust and where do I have to add new values to make this menu slide upon clicking the tab?" --- this totally irrelevant to your "as I'm still trying to learn HTML on my own". It is not learning, it is finding volunteers who would do your work for free. Learning is when you do something easy yourself, not find the snippet somewhere in the internet. -1

Comment: You have multiple IDs with the same name, and you're missing some quotes..

Comment: @zerkms actually I didn't copy and paste from anywhere. I've been getting what I know from http://www.w3schools.com/. And I'm not asking people to do the whole thing for me, I was simply asking how to make the sliding function work, as I don't understand JQuery and where to properly put it so that it works. I was asking for help, which is what I thought this website was meant for, asking for help when you get stumped. Your comment is rude and clearly you didn't understand where I'm coming from, no?

Comment: "and where to properly put it so that it works" -- that's not a learning. Programmers don't just magically put some pixie dust in the code so that it works, programmers **understand** what and why you add. You don't understand jquery? Wonderful - learn its basics and return back. Now you just want us to fix the code you cannot understand (because likely you've took it somewhere, and didn't write it yourself). It sounds rude, yes, but it's just silly when someone says he wants to learn something at first, and later asks to fix his code because he is boring learning basics.

Comment: Obviously you can tell I'm not a programmer. I don't have much experience in this field. I'm a beginner, and every beginner needs a push in the right direction. I've been trying really hard for the past couple of weeks to do this on my own. I've been reading up on html and css and then applying what I have learned and after some trial and error of re-writing lines, some things still won't work. Even after going back and reading up on some sections I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. So I thought I could come here for some help. Unfortunately most people just rather cut down on people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in this form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#tab").toggle(function() { 
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
        $("#tab").html ('-');
    }, function() {
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '-600' }, 500);
        $("#tab").html ('+');
    });

});

</script>

</head>



<body>

<div id="menu" style="
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -600px;
height: 450px;
width: 600px;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
margin:0px;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
font-family:helvetica;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:20px;
opacity:.9;
">

                    <a class="navItem" href="url">about me</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a class="navItem" href="url">book</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <a class="navItem" href="url">resume</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a class="navItem" href="url">ask</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a class="navItem" href="url">archive</a>

<div id="menu-body"
style=height:400px;width:100%;float:left;font-size:100px;text-align:center;">


                    <br>title name</div>

<div id="menu-footer" style="text-align:center;"> website name</div>



<div id="tab" style="
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 100%;
float: right;
font-family: monospace;
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:250px;
cursor:pointer;
">+</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The `$(".tab")` was wrong, it should have been `$("#tab")`.  The first one would select a `<div class="tab">` while the second one matches the `<div id="tab">`. Also the CSS could have been wrong too. It's better to use `<style>` tags for css.

Comment: Ok so I made revisions to my original post- I changed the styling from being behind the <div> tags to css styling in the <head>, to clean it up. Does this look better? Also, what editor are you putting this into, because when I go to test it out, it shows up correctly, but it doesn't toggle back and forth and the menu shows up behind the content of the webpage when it should roll over the content, thus why I have the opacity.

Comment: In my example I used `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` but in yours you have `js/jquery-1.4.min.js`. If you copied that line but didn't change the jquery version, that could be the reason why it doesn't work. About the menu appearing behind the content of the page, you can change the order of elements with the `z-index` property. That property only works for elements which have `position` 'absolute' or 'relative'.